# Integrate an Angular Web Application With Microsoft Project API

Tags: angular, ms-project

I appreciate that this is a very broad question but I would be grateful for some guidance. I need to create a planning web application which though very client specific requires many fundamental project planning demands. I wondered if there was a way to get Microsoft Project to provide the 'heavy lifting' of managing task scheduling, resource management, levelling etc with my web application providing all the client facing UI?

Does anyone have any experience of installing Microsoft Project on a server and then through some API get a web application to create Projects, create and manage Tasks, Resources etc. I would like to use something like Telerik's Gantt Chart to display the data in my Angular web application which will be pulled from the MS Project API. Perhaps I am way off the mark, but it would be a great combination.

Comment: So were you able to find any solution for this?